# Dropdown Check List Pushing Div Downwards Instead of Overlapping

Tags: css

I am using trying to style a .NET DropDownCheckList control to stylistically and functionally fit in one of my user controls.

Currently, I'm working the DropDownCheckList implementation as follows (I plan to convert the table structure to `<div>` and CSS styling once I figure out how to resolve the issue):

```
<asp:Panel ID="CmbCkBxPanel" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="160px" BackColor="White">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEmptyText" runat="server" />
    <table id="CmbCkBxTable" style=" background-color:White; table-layout: fixed; height: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" runat="server">

        <tr id="rowDD" style="border-style: none;background-color: White;" runat="server">
            <td style=" white-space:nowrap;" valign="middle"><asp:textbox id="DDTextBox" ReadOnly="true" style="cursor: default; vertical-align:middle;" runat="server" Width="100%" ToolTip="" BackColor="White" font-names="Arial" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:textbox></td>
            <td id="colDDImage" width="16">
                <asp:Image ID="btnImage" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="z-index: 200; background-color: White; display:none; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color:Black;" id="listdiv" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBList" runat="server" width="100%" style=" text-align:left;  background-color:White;" RepeatColumns="1">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

On page load, the control looks like this (note that I'm using it for the Account and Brand filters):

[image]

When I select the dropdown, however, it pushes the whole div downwards like so:

[image]

**Question**:  Is it possible to overlap the div below, rather than pushing the blue container div downwards? Or is this an issue with the structure of my page?

If you need the container divs and their respective CSS to help me troubleshoot, I can include those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a div to occupy space in your page then you need to set it's position to absolute.